# How to display full object of an array in web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a little problem with display my array items. I try display from localStorage but don't know how to sort by value so I convert all items into an array then sort it. But now I don't know how to display that array. I tried `for` statement and it's only return one object, which mean they stop counting forward for my 'x' to rise. And what it display is only `[object Object]`. Anyone has any suggestion?

```js
function loadPlayer() {

  const lsOutput = document.getElementById("lsOutput");
  var l;
  if (localStorage.length < 5) {
    l = localStorage.length;
  } else {
    l = 5;
  }
  //Sắp xếp localstorage

  var listPlayer = [{
    playerName: '',
    score: ''
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    const key = localStorage.key(i);
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    lsOutput.innerHTML += `${i+1}- ${key}: ${value}<br/>`;
    listPlayer.push({
      playerName: key,
      score: value
    });
  }
  listPlayer.shift();
  //Sort array
  Array.prototype.sortOnValue = function(key) {
    this.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a[key] < b[key]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[key] > b[key]) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }
  listPlayer.sortOnValue("score");
  console.log(listPlayer);
  //const p1Output = document.getElementById("xxxccc");
  for (var x = 0; x < listPlayer.length; x++) {
    //plOutput.innerHTML = document.writeln(listPlayer[x]);
    //plOutput.innerHTML = listPlayer.toString();
    document.getElementById("xxxccc").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(listPlayer[x].toString());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove .toString() its not required.

change the line to

```
document.getElementById("xxxccc").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(listPlayer[x]);
```

Comment: Thanks man. It pull out my object value. But I still don't understand why it pull my last position even though 'x' was 0. Do you know why?

Comment: you are replacing content with innerHTML so its replacing in each iteration and you are left with last  JSON.stringify(listPlayer[lastPlayer.length -1]) shown instead of JSON.stringify(listPlayer[0])

Answer (score 1):

You need use JSON.stringify for objects:

```
lsOutput.innerHTML += `${i+1}- ${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}<br/>`;
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)` if you wanna indent.

Comment: Oh no don't mind that thing above. It's what I use to display item in localStorage and it's work fine. What you want to look at is the thing below. Using JSON stringify turn my [OBJECT OBJECT] into "[OBJECT OBJECT]"